# JSF 2.0 - how to get the property path of a jsf component?

Tags: jsf-2

is there a way to get from a JSF component the property path which is obviously used for updating the model?

I am asking cause we have a concept where the backend validates the whole stuff. Don't ask why but I am not allowed to use JSF build-in validation.
The backend provides ValidationException if for example a property is null but should not be null and the ValidationException contains a list of ValidationInfos containing the full property path for the property the validation info belongs to.

My task is to find a way to map back this info to the corresponding JSF component to be able to show the message for the correct JSF component.
It is allowed for me to register/attach some kind of little helpers to the component to make it easier for mapping back the infos.

My first approach was to write a tag handler and in the tag handler to find out the property path and the root bean. But I am lost there cause we are also using JSF 2.0 components with deferred value expression so I see at the moment a value expression like vor example #{cc.attrs.value} but I am interested in the "caller" expression like for example #{aBean.street} which is obiously the property path for updating the model.

```xml
<composite:interface>
   <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" styleClass="#{!component.valid ? 'col2 error' : 'col2'}">
        <my-components:registerTagHandler value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
    </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

Maybe there are other approaches or other ideas out there. It would be helpful for me to get some hints/ideas.

Best Regards,
Walter

PS: sorry for my crude english cause I am not a native english speaker.